# Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals in an array

Tags: matlab

thıs ıs my code ... but tehere ıs a problem ı guess about my type defınıtıon...

```
fat=[9.5 26.5 7.8 17.8 31.4 25.9 27.4 27.2 31.2 34.6 42.5 28.8 33.4 30.2 34.1 32.9 41.2 35.7]
fatSum=0;
for j:18
    fatSum=fatSum+fat(1,i)
end
fatMean=fatSum/18
```

Comment: Also see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20054047/subscript-indices-must-either-be-real-positive-integers-or-logicals-generic-sol) for [the generic solution to this problem](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20054048/983722).

Answer (score 2):

Your loop statement is broken.  Where you have for `j:18` you should have for `j = 1:18`.

Your loop is unnecessary.  You can sum the elements in an array like this: `fatsum = sum(fat)`.